# Metrizability of topology of compact convergence

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, frechet-manifold

Let $X$ be a separable metric space and $Y$ be a second-countable $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space.  Then the compact-convergence (compact-open) topology on $C(Y,X)$ is metrizable with metric
$$
d(f,g):= \sum_{n =0}^{\infty} \frac1{2^n} \sup_{y \in K_n} \min\left\{d_X(f(y),g(y)),1\right\},
$$
where $\{K_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a countable compact cover of $Y$ and $d_X$ is the metric on $X$.  Moreover, if $X$ is Banach then $C(Y,X)$ is a Fréchet space.

This is easy to show, but I'm looking for a reference to this result.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Corona prevents me from checking the bookshelf in my office. Just note that the formula is not completely correct, if the metric $d_X$ is not bounded the series may diverge. You should replace $d_X$ by $\min\{d_X,1\}$.

Comment: Haha, ya same here (not the biggest fan from working from home).  Thanks for the tip, I made the modification :)

Comment: Might be an overkill, but look at Bourbaki's *General Topology* X, §3.1, Corollary.

Comment: Also note that X can be isometrically embeded in a separable Banach space E, so that C(X,Y) is a subspace of C(Y,E), a Frėchet space.

Comment: There are two points here, one very elementary, one rather subtle.  The first one involves the metrisability.  This is more transparent in the following version. If a uniformity is defined by a sequence $(d_n)$ of pseudometrics, then it can be be specifies by a single one. The standard ploy is to use $\sum \frac 1{2^n}\frac {d_n}{1+d_ n}$.  Separability plays no role.

Comment: This gives the metrisability condition in the second one.  Here it is the completeness which is tricky.  For this you need some version of the Kelley condition, i.e., that a function is continuous whenever its restriction to compacta is.  I am not a point set topologist but flicking through my home library suggests that your  conditions might not suffice.

Comment: How does that work for the space of rationals where you take each $K_n$ a singleton (using some enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$)? Don't you get the topolog of pointwise convergence that way?

Comment: True, I guess there should be some type of topological regulairty like contractability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Engelking (exercise 3.4E, which is based on a [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969087?seq=1) by Arens):

> If $C(X,\Bbb R)$ (with the compact-open topology and $X$ Tychonoff) is first countable, then $X$ is hemicompact.

A Hausdorff space $X$ is hemicompact if there is a countable family $K_n$ of compact subsets of $X$ such that every compact $K \subseteq X$ is a subset of some $K_n$ (i.e. all compacta of $X$ ordered under inclusion has countable cofinality). For $X$ second-countable, hemicompactness is equivalent to local compactness.

So a space like $\Bbb Q$, which is not locally compact but is $\sigma$-compact has  $C(X,\Bbb R)$ not even first countable, let alone metrisable.

But Arens showed in that same paper (ex. 4.2H in Engelking) that for hemicompact $X$ and metrisable $Y$ , $C(X,Y)$ in the compact-open topology *is* metrisable, using a metric like yours.

So the moral is: you need to add "locally compact" to your $Y$ (and the space then becomes hemicompact and all is well).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great answer Henno.  I really appreciate all the references!